# Comparing 2 fields within a Mongo Aggregation Query

Tags: php, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection in my Mongo Database called `WorkOrder` with 2 fields `DateComplete` and `DateDue`. Using those 2 fields I'd like to use the aggregation framework to count the number of 'Late' Work Orders by comparing the two fields. However the research I've found hasn't had any useful ways to format the query so that the 'Late' Work Orders will be filtered through. Does anyone know of a way to format a Mongo DB Aggregation Query (preferably in PHP) that can compare 2 fields in the collection?

EDIT:

An example entry in WorkOrder might look like

_id

some mongo id

DateDue

2014-10-10

DateCompleted

2014-10-12

This entry would want to be filtered through since DateCompleted is greater than DateDue. I didn't know about the $cond operator so I haven't tried anything for that yet.

EDIT:

After trying @BatScream's suggestion with the following query in my PHP script

```
array(
    '$cond' => array(
        'if' => array(
            'dateDue' => array(
                '$lt' => 'dateComplete
            )
        )
    )
)
```

However the `MongoCollection::Aggregate` function told me that `$cond` wasn't a recognized operator.

EDIT: @BatScream's answer seems to work but I wasn't aware of the fact that the group operator doesn't work properly after a $project is applied. I was hoping to be able to group these document on another field `cID`, is that possible?

Comment: You need to use the `$cond` and `$gt` operators together to project a new field and perform the calculations based on the projected field. Please post some sample data and what you have tried.

Comment: Can you paste the full pipeline and the error about `$cond`? It's definitely a real agg operator, but it belongs in the `$project` stage, not the `$match` stage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below aggregation pipeline would give you the result, considering your fields are of `ISODate` type. If not i suggest you to store them as `ISODate` type and **not** Strings.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{$project:{"isLateWorkOrder":{$cond:[{$lt:["$dateDue","$dateCompleted"]},
                          true,false]}}},
{$match:{"isLateWorkOrder":true}},
{$group:{"_id":null,"lateWorkOrders":{$sum:1}}},
{$project:{"_id":0,"lateWorkOrders":1}}
])
```

The PHP syntax should look similar to,

```
$projA = array("isLateWorkOrder" => 
                 array("$cond" => 
                             array(array("$lt" =>
           array("$dateDue","$dateCompleted")),
           true,false)))                         
$matchA = array("isLateWorkOrder"  => true)
$grp =  array("_id" => null,"lateWorkOrders" => array("$sum" => 1))
$projB = array("_id" => 0,"lateWorkOrders" => 1)

$pipeline = array($projA,$matchA,$grp,$projB);
$someCol -> aggregate($pipeline)
```

or, simply using the `count` function:

```
db.collection.count({$where:"this.dateDue < this.dateCompleted"})
```

Comment: This code mostly works except that any quote in PHP with a $ in it should be in single quotes or the $ needs to be escaped so that PHP doesn't interpret it as a variable.